# Why am I receiving an error when trying to add a custom struts2 validator?

Tags: java, xml, validation, struts2

I created a custom validator, but when I try defining it in my **validators.xml**, I get an exception.

- I confirmed the error only occurs when I add the following line of code to my **validators.xml**:

  ```
  <validator 
  name="validateSin"
  class="ca.gc.cra.mmbb.mba.validators.SinFieldCheck"/>
  ```
- Even if I make the SinFieldCheck validator completely basic, the error still occurs (which confirms the issue is not with the validator itself).
- The error occurs despite not using this custom validator in my **-validation.xml** files
- If I remove this custom validator, and simply use default validators, my validation works as expected.

---

Based on the research I've done this could be a DTD or struts versioning issue... my **validators.xml** DTD is:

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
"-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator Config 1.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-config-1.0.dtd">
```

The struts version I am using is **2.3.16.2**.

Note that there is some struts 1 in my project.. I doubt this would cause any confilct though...

---

The error I am receiving:

```
2016-06-29 12:49:48,146 | WARN  |           | com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn(CommonsLogger.java:56)               - Unable to load config class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor at interceptor - zip:C:/APPS/Oracle/Middleware_10.3.6/user_projects/domains/d-domain01/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_mmbb.mba_ear/1chf7n/war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:181:127 probably due to a missing jar, which might be fine if you never plan to use the validation interceptor
2016-06-29 12:49:48,146 | WARN  |           | com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn(CommonsLogger.java:56)               - Unable to load config class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor at interceptor - zip:C:/APPS/Oracle/Middleware_10.3.6/user_projects/domains/d-domain01/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_mmbb.mba_ear/1chf7n/war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:181:127 probably due to a missing jar, which might be fine if you never plan to use the validation interceptor
2016-06-29 12:49:48,146 | ERROR |           | com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.error(CommonsLogger.java:38)              - Actual exception
Caught Exception while registering Interceptor class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor - interceptor - zip:C:/APPS/Oracle/Middleware_10.3.6/user_projects/domains/d-domain01/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_mmbb.mba_ear/1chf7n/war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:181:127
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultInterceptorFactory.buildInterceptor(DefaultInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(ObjectFactory.java:202)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder.constructInterceptorReference(InterceptorBuilder.java:70)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.lookupInterceptorReference(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:1110)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStack(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:928)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStacks(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:941)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptors(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:964)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:533)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:292)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:258)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:343)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.loadFilter(FilterManager.java:96)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.preloadFilters(FilterManager.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1872)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:59)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:301)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:492)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:530)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:528)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:584)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:528)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.injectInternalBeans(ObjectFactory.java:159)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:184)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultInterceptorFactory.buildInterceptor(DefaultInterceptorFactory.java:42)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:469)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:299)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:502)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:539)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:593)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:301)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:438)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:469)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:484)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.access$000(ContainerImpl.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:299)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:502)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:539)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:593)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:537)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:130)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:447)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:499)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:426)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/validators/FieldValidatorSupport
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:144)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.getClassInstance(ObjectFactory.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:181)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultValidatorFactory.buildValidator(DefaultValidatorFactory.java:29)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildValidator(ObjectFactory.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFileParser.parseValidatorDefinitions(DefaultValidatorFileParser.java:131)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFactory.retrieveValidatorConfiguration(DefaultValidatorFactory.java:201)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFactory.parseValidators(DefaultValidatorFactory.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFactory.<init>(DefaultValidatorFactory.java:61)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.validators.FieldValidatorSupport
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    ... 112 more
```

Comment: ... The error explicitly states what the problem is.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't know how to fix it though... I have the correct DTDs.. validation works if I remove the custom interceptor...

Comment: You are  missing Struts2 core libraries.

Comment: @RomanC I have them all.. I think the problem might be I'm also using struts1 libraries (ex: commons-io-1.1 AND commons-io-2.2, commons-digester-1.6 AND commons-digester-2.0)... Could this be an issue?

Comment: Exactly it's the issue.